# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields if one field key is a color picker how to use that for heading and link styles within the wysiwyg?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, api, advanced-custom-fields

Hi I am trying to allow the color picker field to determine the events headings and link colours within the wysiwyg tinymce editor so that the client can see it immediately. I am wondering if I need to call the post id or global post to get this to work? I did try it but it still didn't work. I guess I am not understanding the way it should work.

I have tried a php function as well as a javascript api.
This doesn't work:

`````
````
function my_acf_admin_head() {    
$colours = get_field( 'choose_main_headings_and_link_colour' ); ?>
    
<style type="text/css">

 body[data-id="acf-editor-153"] a, h1 { color:"<?php echo $colours; ?>";
  }
</style>

<?php
}
add_action('acf/input/admin_head', 'my_acf_admin_head');


````
`````

Do I need to add something like this to the above?

```
`
$colours = get_field('choose_main_headings_and_link_colour', $post_id); 

`
```

Or do I need to echo the ?

This works to actually manipulate the tinymce acf editor though it doesn't help with styles and only allows one field key not multiple editors.

```
add_action('acf/input/admin_footer', function(){
    ?>
    <script>

        acf.addFilter('wysiwyg_tinymce_settings', function( mceInit, id, field ){
            if(field.get('key') !== 'field_63f8196bb4c98') {
                
                return mceInit;
            }
            
            mceInit.block_formats = 'Paragraph=p;Heading 4=h4';
            return mceInit;
        });

    </script>
    <?php
    });
```

It seems like it should be a simple method but am not having any luck. If the post has to be published first then that didn't work either.

Am I going in the right direction?
Thanks